# How can I change --rpc-max-connections on already running substrate-based node?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, rpc, custom-rpc

I have already running substrate-based node and I started to get error:

> 429 Too many requests: Too many connections.

This happens due to HTTP requests that my FE produces. After research I understand that I should configure `--rpc-max-connections` parameter, but I didn't find any info about how can I update this parameter on the already running network?
Maybe I missed something? If yes, please let me know how can I do it)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this can only be modified during startup.

At present, this flag does not support dynamic updates.

Comment: Thanks
So, I should restart my node without cleaning state just add this parameter to startup script?!

Comment: @ArtemLevchuk yes!